# Modify Regular Expression for "dd/MM/yyyy"

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, expression

I have the regular expression for "dd/MM/yyyy" which works fine,

```
"^([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$"
```

but I want to modify this so it also accepts 00/MM/2014. 
My program interpret this as all the days in a specific month. For example 00/04/2014
means all the dates in month of April.

Can someone tell me what kind of change I need to make to above script to make this happen?

Here is the code which I am using it in :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" MaxLength="1"  CssClass="MainContent"
                         style="text-align:justify" ValidationGroup="MKE" Width="130px" />
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBntCalc" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                         ImageUrl="images\calendar-schedulehs.png" />
                                    <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" 
                                        AcceptNegative="Left" DisplayMoney="Left" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" 
                                        mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" MessageValidatorTip="true" 
                                        OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" 
                                        TargetControlID="TextBox5"  />
                                         <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator2" runat="server" 
                                        ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender2" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
                                        Display="Dynamic" EmptyValueBlurredText="*"  ValidationExpression="^(?:[012]?[0-9]|3[01])[./-](?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[./-](?:[0-9]{2}){1,2}$"
                                        InvalidValueMessage="Date is invalid" ValidationGroup="MKE1" />
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"  Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                        PopupButtonID="ImgBntCalc" TargetControlID="TextBox5" />
```

Comment: That regex won't work for `dd/MM/yyyy` - `31/01/2014' would not pass.

Comment: what change do I have to make so it accept also 31/01/2014?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well right now it's built for `MM/dd/yyyy` (the first group can only contain 0-12).  But here's one that works for `dd/mm/yyyy` and allows for a `00` or `0` day:

```
"^([0]?[0-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$"
```

Comment: Just to confirm is that just switching the first two number groups around so that it is as before except dd/MM instead of MM/dd?

Comment: And adding `00` as a valid day (changed the `[1-9]` to `[0-9]` in the first grouping)

Comment: FYI, you don't want the pipe inside of square brackets; they signify alternation by definition (e.g. `[01]` is correct, not `[0|1]`, unless you want to accept `|` as a valid date character!)

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (format is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), in most cases it's the easier way to parse dates...

Comment: This isn't parsing dates though unless you are suggesting that the OP should validate through attempting to parse. In that case though they would then be further from being able to accept 00/MM than they are now... I'd suggest making this a comment or expanding your answer to address the problem more clearly.

Comment: You're right, I missed the fact that he wasn't *describing* the date format, but specifying the literal input that his program accepts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd submit that there's too much going on in this expression.  Subjective, to be sure, but if this were my code I'd make a looser regex and do the validation in code.  I find it's way easier to come back six months later and understand that, rather than a complicated regex.

That being said...

```
^(00|0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$
```

**EDIT**

By way of explanation, here's the day portion of the expression, commented:

```
^(
  00          # match the literal string '00'
  | 0?[1-9]   # or, match 1-9, optionally prefixed with '0'
  | [12][0-9] # or, match days 10-29
  | 3[01]     # or, match days 30 and 31
 )
```

Judging by your comments, it sounds like there's a problem with how you're actually using the regex in code.  Can you post the code where you're actually using the expression?

Comment: That string validates for me, actually - I just copy/pasted it from my answer into code and ran it; `00/01/2014` matches successfully.  What are you seeing?  Can you update your answer with the code you have that doesn't accept this date?

Comment: Sorry for the delay , I just updated above with code you asked for. I appropriate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

dd/mm/yyyy:

```
^(?:[012]?[0-9]|3[01])[./-](?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[./-](?:[0-9]{2}){1,2}$
```

mm/dd/yyyy:

```
^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[./-](?:[012]?[0-9]|3[01])[./-](?:[0-9]{2}){1,2}$
```

Comment: @user3033921: Yes it does, with the first `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
^([0]?[0-9]|[1][0-2])[.\/-]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[.\/-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$
```

**IN ASPX**

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" MaxLength="1"  CssClass="MainContent"
                             style="text-align:justify" ValidationGroup="MKE" Width="130px" />
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBntCalc" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                             ImageUrl="images\calendar-schedulehs.png" />
                                        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" 
                                            AcceptNegative="Left" DisplayMoney="Left" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" 
                                            mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" MessageValidatorTip="true" 
                                            OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" 
                                            TargetControlID="TextBox5"  />
                                             <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator2" runat="server" 
                                            ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender2" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
                                            Display="Dynamic" EmptyValueBlurredText="*"  ValidationExpression="^([0]?[0-9]|[1][0-2])[.\/-]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[.\/-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$"
                                            InvalidValueMessage="Date is invalid" ValidationGroup="MKE1" />
                                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"  Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                            PopupButtonID="ImgBntCalc" 

    TargetControlID="TextBox5" />
```

CHECK HERE [DATE VALIDATION](http://rubular.com/r/6gVkvuYV4d)